# Laplace equation on the upper half plane with boundary conditions along x=0

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Consider the 2d Laplace equation
$$\Delta u=0$$
on the upper half plane
$$\{(x,y)| y \geq 0\}$$

I know the problem is well posed if you specify Dirichlet boundary conditions at $y=0$, and a suitable boundedness as $y\to\infty$:
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$

I know it is ill-posed if you specify both the function and its derivative at $y=0$:
$$u(x,0)=f(x) \,, \quad u_y(x,0)=g(x) $$

I need to impose more unconventional boundary conditions:
$$u(0,y)=h_1(y) \,, \qquad u_x(0,y)=h_2(y)\,, \quad y\geq 0$$
namely specifying both the function and its derivative at $x=0$.

Is this problem well-posed?

Any help or references to the appropriate literature would be insanely helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you also want to keep the boundary conditions along $y=0$ also? So that $$u(x,0) = f(x), \ u(0,y) = h_1(y), \ u_x(0,y) =h_2(y)$$ with $f(0) = h_1(0)$ or just the conditions along $x=0$?

Comment: No, I impose no boundary condition at $y=0$.

Comment: You are imposing conditions in the middle of the region. That's not typicall something you can do because you also want to satisfy the Laplace equation in the region.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts, I understand it is unconventional, but this is the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with the Dirichlet condition is not well-posed. The function $v \colon (x,y) \mapsto y$ verifies $\Delta v = 0$ on $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \colon y > 0\}$ and $v(\cdot,y=0) = 0$.

So for every solution $u$ of your problem, $u+v$ is also a solution.

Conditions at $y \to + \infty$ are lacking.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I edited the question. Any clue on the answer to the other problem?

Comment: Well I don't understand. Your unconventional conditions are posed on the half-line $\{(0,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \colon y \in \mathbb R\}$ which is not a subset of the boundary $\{(x,0) \in \mathbb R^2 \colon x \in \mathbb R\}$ of the half-plane $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \colon y > 0\}$... So these are not boundary conditions.

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear, I am only imposing my boundary conditions at $y\geq0$. So it is in the upper half plane.

Comment: I still don't get it. You have a domain $\Omega$ that is the upper-half plane. You can impose boundary conditions only on the boundary $\partial \Omega$ of the upper-half plane which is $\{(x,0)\}$.

Comment: Indeed, you are right they are not boundary conditions per say since they are not imposed on the boundary. But I am looking for a solution that satisfies the conditions  given at x=0, or rather I want to know if a smooth such solution exists.